# Set <li> item as active on navigating to particular page

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, navbar, master-pages

I am working on an Asp.Net website where I replaced the default horizontal  navbar in the Site.Master with the navbar available in the AdminLTE example. [AdminLTE Example](https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html).

The vertical navbar looks like this

[image: Vertical Navbar]

The code for the navbar is as under

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
                <li class="header">Navigation</li>
                <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
                <li>
                    <a href="Default.aspx">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        <span>Home</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="About.aspx">
                        <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
                        <span>About</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Contact.aspx">
                        <i class="fa fa-address-book"></i>
                        <span>Contact</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="treeview">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
                        <span class="pull-right-container">
                            <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="treeview-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I want to set the list item class to **active** once a user navigates to that particular page. For an instance, if the user clicks on the **About** link it will be redirected to the about page and then on that page, the class of about link should be changed to **active**

I tried using this particular script but it didn't work for me

```
$(function() {
 var pgurl = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
 $("ul li a").each(function(){
      if($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '' )
      $(this).addClass("active");
 })
```

});

Don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Seems to work for me but, to troubleshoot, I suggest checking the value of `pgurl` to make sure it's what you expect, e.g. `console.log(pgurl);`.

Comment: what does your link look like after you go to "About" website.com/about ?

Comment: I just noticed that you said you want to set the "list item" class. In your code, you're setting the class of the `<a>` rather than the `<li>`. Is that what you mean? If so, see [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).

Comment: @Innervisions its localhost:5583/About.aspx

Comment: @showdev I want to set the <li> class to active

Answer (score 1):

Your `each` function is based on a selector for `<a>` elements.
So, you are current adding the class to the `<a>` element, as referenced by `$(this)`.
It seems that you want to add it to the associated `<li>` element.

I recommend jQuery's [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/).

> Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```js
var test_url = 'localhost:5583/About.aspx';

$(function() {
  var pgurl = test_url.substr(test_url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $("ul li a").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("href") == pgurl || $(this).attr("href") == '')
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
  <li class="header">Navigation</li>
  <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
  <li>
    <a href="Default.aspx">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="About.aspx">
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
      <span>About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="Contact.aspx">
      <i class="fa fa-address-book"></i>
      <span>Contact</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Alternatively, and mainly as a demonstration, you could change your selector to `li` and test the `href`s of descendant `<a>` elements.

```js
var test_url = 'localhost:5583/About.aspx';

$(function() {
  var pgurl = test_url.substr(test_url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
  $("ul li").each(function() {
    if ($('a', this).attr("href") == pgurl || $('a', this).attr("href") == '')
      $(this).addClass("active");
  })
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sidebar-menu" data-widget="tree">
  <li class="header">Navigation</li>
  <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
  <li>
    <a href="Default.aspx">
      <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
      <span>Home</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="About.aspx">
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
      <span>About</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="Contact.aspx">
      <i class="fa fa-address-book"></i>
      <span>Contact</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="treeview">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
      <span class="pull-right-container">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="treeview-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```